# Deleting multiple table entries with check boxes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I was wondering if there is a way to delete multiple table entries on my index.html.erb page by using checkboxes next to each entry, and then having a "delete selected entries" button at the end of it.
Sorry if this is a simple question, but I only recently started coding in rails (and it is also rails 4 which has very few guides).

Thank you for your time!

EDIT reply for Mirko Akkov:

```
def destroy
User.where(id: params[:ids]).destroy_all
@user.destroy
redirect...
end
```

and the index.html:

```
<table>
...
...
<td><span id='pdf_link'><%= link_to 'Delete', user, title: 'Delete user', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></span></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ids[]"></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what kind entries ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: I have a users controller and I want to be able to delete multiple users at once, without having to press the "delete" button for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this by passing an array of ids.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ids[]">
```

after this, just pass the array of ids to the destroy method

```
MyModel.where(id: params[:ids]).destroy_all
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if this is not working for rails4 but I can't seem to get this to work:
 1) If I only tick one checkbox and click the delete box it works (but just deletes one of course).
 2) If I tick multiple boxes and try to delete, nothing gets deleted.

Comment: I'll post it in the OP as it seems a bit messy here

Comment: just realised I am probably not passing the ids to the method but I am not sure I know how to do that.